# IModel.GetRelationalModel is not copying annotations

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, ef-core-6.0

When converting from an IModel to a RelationalModel either by:

- Using the .GetRelationalModel() extension for IModel.
- Using RelationalModel constructor which takes an IModel

Annotations from the orignal IModel are not preserved. Meaning functions like IMigrationsModelDiffer.GetDifferences() don't work as intended. Manually copying the annotations after the fact also doesn't help as GetDifferences() won't use runtime annotations.

Is there an alternative way to create the RelationalModel which preserves these annotations? Or an alternative to GetDifferences which will use runtime annotations?

```
var oldRelationalModel = oldModel.GetRelationalModel();
            Log.Information("Old IModel Annotations: {0}", oldModel.GetAnnotations().Count());
            Log.Information("Old RelationalModel Annotations: {0}", oldRelationalModel.GetAnnotations().Count());
            
var newRelationalModel = newModel.GetRelationalModel();
            Log.Information("Old IModel Annotations: {0}", newModel.GetAnnotations().Count());
            Log.Information("Old RelationalModel Annotations: {0}", newRelationalModel.GetAnnotations().Count());
```

```
[15:57:46 INF] Old IModel Annotations: 5
[15:57:46 INF] Old RelationalModel Annotations: 0
[15:57:46 INF] Old IModel Annotations: 5
[15:57:46 INF] Old RelationalModel Annotations: 0
```

Comment: May be they are not supposed to be preserved "by design". It's tricky because all these things are not documented. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Try to get additional annotations from `IRelationalAnnotationProvider` service.

Comment: @IvanStoev im trying to compare stored model to the current model of the DB Context. The stored model is stored as the scaffold code for the context which is then compiled to and IModel and in theory compared to the current DBContext using GetDifferences. But since ef6 get differences uses RelationalModel rather than IModel hence my attempt to convert. Unfortunately GetDifferences relies on the annotations to work its magic.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv How would I go about doing that?

Comment: `context.GetService<IRelationalAnnotationProvider>()` and examine available methods.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I might be misunderstanding but `IRelationalAnnotationProvider` only provides read access to annotations. I need to add them into the existing `RelationalModel` or ideally have them copied across when transforming from `IModel`

Comment: @HaydenBrowne You'd better post your question to their GitHub issue tracker.